# Query data for the last day of previous month into SSRS Report Cell

Tags: reporting-services, expression

I'm in the process of building a report and I'm stuck with one requirement. two of the columns in the output of my stored procedure are `Accomplishments` and `UpdateDate`. Now I have to write an expression for the accomplishment field such that it takes the `Accomplishments` values corresponding to the latest date in previous month in the `UpdateDate` column..

There are multiple `Accomplishment` values for every month and all of them are updated at different dates.. please help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I did:

'
SELECT * FROM (

SELECT
 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ProjectID ORDER BY UpdateDate DESC) AS RN,
 *

FROM TableName

WHERE UpdateDate BETWEEN DateAdd(mm, DateDiff(mm, 31, GetDate()), 0) AND DateAdd(mm, DateDiff(mm, 0, GetDate()), 0)'

) AS x

WHERE RN = 1

Courtesy Naomi N from MSDN Forums..